# spring - configure domain for JSESSIONID cookie

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, cookies

I'm working on a java spring mvc application. My application has some subdomains like this:

`sub1.test.com`

`sub2.test.com`

My problem is when I login form url `sub1.test.com/login` and try to go to `sub2.test.com\home`, spring redirects me to `sub2.test.com/login`. When I inspect cookies from browser console panel, There is a `JSESSIONID` cookie with domain `subxx.test.com`. I think it should be `test.com` instead. But I don't know how can I configure spring session id domain.

Note I'm using apache tomcat 8.0.11.

Comment: I think your server enabled `sticky session`. can you please check it?

Comment: Thank you for your response, How can I disable it?

Comment: I don't have so much idea about how to disabled it. which load balancer you used? mod_jk, haproxy or what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution myself. Just adding below code inside `conf/context.xml` solved the problem:

```
<context  sessionCookiePath="/" sessionCookieDomain="test.ir">
...
</context>
```